# repeated extern declarations of qualified identifiers C++

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Why is it that qualified names cannot be re-declared inside functions?

The following code fails to compile (in MSVC2015 and clang)

```
int i;

namespace N
{
int j;
}

void foo()
{
    extern int i;
    extern int i;
    extern int N::j;
    extern int N::j;
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

However, if we move the two lines `extern int N::j;` to just before `void foo()` then the code compiles fine.

---

**UPDATE** It is noteworthy that

1. repeated declarations of unqualified names do work,
2. both `::i` and `::N::j` were already defined in their respective declarations,
3. `::N::j` is not visible to `foo`
4. the grammar does allow `extern int ::N::j` and *it is not a definition*
5. the following code also fails (thank to T.C. for pointing this out)

.

```
int i;
void foo()
{
    extern int ::i;
}
```

6. the following code works in MSVC but it gives a warning in clang

.

```
int i;
extern int ::i;
```

Comment: Nothing to do with the repeat. Even `void foo() { extern int N::j; }` doesn't compile.

Comment: @T.C. updated question (thanks).

Comment: See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#482

Answer (score 2, accepted):

T.C. directed me to [dcl.meaning]p1

> … When the declarator-id is qualified, the declaration shall refer to a previously declared member of the class or namespace to which the qualifier refers (or, in the case of a namespace, of an element of the inline namespace set of that namespace (7.3.1)) or to a specialization thereof …

It seems to me that this is a case where the standard is not faithfully represented by the implementations.

Comment: In particular, pre-CWG482, qualified names in declarations are disallowed with only a few exceptions not relevant here. CWG482's resolution relaxed the restriction, but the compilers have not been updated, it seems, to implement the change.

Answer (score 1):

It is the namespace member definition vs. declaration issue here.  Please see C++11 spec:

> 7.3.1.2 Namespace member definitions [namespace.memdef]
>
> 1 Members (including explicit specializations of templates (14.7.3)) of a
>   namespace can be defined within that namespace. 
>   [ Example: namespace X
>   { void f() { / ... / } } —end example ]
>
> 2 Members of a named
>   namespace can also be defined outside that namespace by explicit
>   qualification (3.4.3.2) of the name being defined, provided that the
>   entity being defined was already declared in the namespace and the
>   definition appears after the point of declaration in a namespace that
>   encloses the declaration’s namespace.

Therefore, the revised code below compiles.

```
int i;

namespace N
{
    int j;

    void foo()
    {
        extern int i;
        extern int j;
    }
}

void foo()
{
    extern int i;

    using namespace N;
    extern int j;
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a generic example of using `extern` with `namespace`:
In one CPP file:

```
namespace N
{
    int j;
}
```

In its header file:

```
namespace N
{
    extern int j;
}
```

---

Update:

### More on extern, namespace, declaration and definition

The :: scope resolution operator cannot be use for declaration.  It may be used for definition. Using :: for `extern` declaration would be ill-formed.
Please see C++11 spec:

> 7.5 Linkage specifications [dcl.link] 
>   ... ...
>   4 Linkage specifications nest. When linkage specifications nest, the innermost
>   one determines the language linkage. **A linkage specification does not
>   establish a scope. A linkage-specification shall occur only in
>   namespace scope (3.3).** In a linkage-specification, the specified
>   language linkage applies to the function types of all function
>   declarators, function names with external linkage, and variable names
>   with external linkage declared within the linkage-specification.
>
> 3.3.6 Namespace scope [basic.scope.namespace]
>
> 1 The declarative region of a namespace-definition is its namespace-body. …

```
// Compiled with VC2013.
// extern int ::i;   // error C2039: 'i' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
extern int i;     // declaration  
int i;  // definition

namespace N
{
    extern int j;  // declaration
}
int N::j;  // definition
namespace N
{
     // int j;  // definition
}

void foo()
{
    // extern int ::i;  // fatal error C1506: unrecoverable block scoping error
    extern int i;     // declaration  
    // extern int N::j;  // error C2086: 'int N::j' : redefinition
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The rule you quote applies to definitions but an `extern` declaration is not a definition [basic.def]/2: "A declaration is a definition unless […] it contains the extern specifier and neither an initializer nor …"

Comment: Added rule for namespace scope declaration.  Please see the "More on extern, namespace, declaration and definition" section.

Comment: If you want to call something "undefined behavior", you'll need something much stronger than an irrelevant standard quote on declaratory regions and an *ipse dixit*, especially as this is not something obviously impossible to diagnose.

Comment: I agree that names can be introduced into a namespace only within that namespace. However, `extern int ::i` would not be introducing `i` into the global space. It would be introducing the name `i` into the current space so that it refers to the global `i`, wouldn't it?

Comment: Please see C++11 Standard:  7.5 Linkage specifications [dcl.link] ... ...
4 Linkage specifications nest. When linkage specifications nest, the innermost one determines the language linkage. A linkage specification does not establish a scope. A linkage-specification shall occur only in namespace scope (3.3).